# image corruption for images > 5500 kB when using Android Camera API

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I'm programming an app that automatically takes pictures at certain intervals using the Android Camera API. It's working more or less fine, but I have a weird problem: About 2/3 of all my images are slightly corrupt, as can be seen in this image

[image: corrupt image].

Notably, this only happens for images that are larger than about 5500 KB (the largest uncorrupted image is 5419 KB, the smallest corrupted one is 5510 KB)
Does anyone have an idea what might cause such a corruption?

Here's my code for saving the image in my implementation of onPictureTaken:

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken");
    File pictureFileDir = getDir();
    if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Can't create directory to save image.");
        return;
    }
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    final String photoFile = date + ".jpg";
    final String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;
    final File pictureFile = new File(filename);

    try {
        BufferedOutputStream buf = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pictureFile));
        buf.write(data);
        buf.flush();
        buf.close();
    } catch (Exception error) {
        Log.d(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "File" + filename
                + "not saved: " + error.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Edit: I solved this problem. It turns out that if you acquire images without a visible preview texture, you still need to asssign a preview size in the Camera.Parameters. If you set this preview size to the actual image size, images of size > 5500 kB are acquired correctly.

Comment: Are they only slightly corrupt, or are some of them almost completely grey?
Some code for the save event would be great.
It looks like either writing or reading the data goes wrong.

Comment: I edie my original post Tod include source. it is always only the lower third of the image that is affected